# no stdlib hinting in Goland IDE with custom GOPATH and govendor

Tags: python, go, goland

I'm using Goland 2017.3 with Go 1.9.2, and have a custom GOPATH with govendor that replicates the DigitalOcean monorepo, as explained here: https://blog.digitalocean.com/cthulhu-organizing-go-code-in-a-scalable-repo/

The structure looks like this:

```
gocode
├── .env.sh
├── bin
├── src
│   └── acmecorp
│       ├── teams
│       └── vendor
├── pkg
```

and `.env.sh` looks like this:

```
SCRIPT=`python -c "import os,sys; print(os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(sys.argv[1])))" "${0}"`
GOCODE=$(dirname $SCRIPT)
export GOPATH="$GOCODE"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

I have no issue building code with `source .env.sh` and `govendor build`. `govendor` resolves all dependencies and builds the project.

However, when I attempt to set up `GOPATH` in GoLand and set `PROJECT GOPATH` to `$HOME/gocode`, GoLand stops recognizing the stdlib because it starts looking for the stdlib in `vendor`: `$HOME/gocode/src/acmecorp/vendor/time has no buildable Go source files`. If I remove the `PROJECT GOPATH` it finds the stdlib but not the code in the mono repo.

How can I get GoLand to stop looking in `vendor` for the stdlib?

Edit: `GOROOT` is kept as standard in the IDE: [screenshot of GOROOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeuiH.png)

Comment: Are you changing `GOROOT` anywhere?

Comment: I edited the post above with an answer to this comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open an issue on the tracker tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and attach the IDE logs via Help | Collect and Show Logs in.... You can lock the visibility of the logs to `jetbrains-team` and `GoLand team` only so that the logs are not publicly accessible.

This looks either like a bug in the IDE or a configuration issue on your side but it's hard to tell which without logs. Thank you.